# Add regression line to logarithmic x scale

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, regression, logarithm

I have some data over a very wide x range which I'm plotting using a logarithmic x axis in R. When I plot the data using MS Excel and add a linear trendline, the resulting output is what I would hope to see given my dataset and expected outcome (image below).

[image: Excel scatterplot]

I'd like to achieve this using R. I can plot the data OK, and run the regression model, but R doesn't seem to want to add the regression line/curve.

Here's my data:

```
data <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(
      6.37E-05,
      0.000584271,
      0.001044085,
      0.00011272,
      3.95E-05,
      6.05E-05,
      0.000277963,
      0.001800305,
      3.70E-05,
      0.002588335,
      0.000710123,
      0.000148309,
      0.001069184,
      0.001877917,
      0.01086776,
      0.043686462,
      0.000276426
    ),
    y = c(
      -0.3375,
      -0.35,
      -0.35,
      -0.35,
      -0.3,
      -0.35,
      -0.3625,
      -0.375,
      -0.3,
      -0.3625,
      -0.3,
      -0.3375,
      -0.29,
      -0.34,
      -0.4,
      -0.48,
      -0.3375
    )
  )
```

And here's the code I've been trying thus far.

```
attach(data)
    plot(data$x,data$y,log="x",xlab="independent variable",
     ylab="dependent variable")
model<-lm(data$y~data$x)
abline(model) # THIS STEP DOESN'T WORK
```

I have three queries:

1). How do I show the regression line on the y~logx plot in basic R?

2). How do I repeat 1). using ggplot?

3). How do I I find the (log)x value when the regression line/curve begins to 'dip'?

Thank you.

Comment: Re: 3). The regression line is constantly decreasing, with constant slope. At no point does it "begin" to dip.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make the example reproducible?
I think this might work though.

```
dataframe %>%
ggplot(aes(x = log(x), y = y) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
 xlab("independent variable")
```

This uses dplyr and ggplot2.

Comment: I just get an error message when I try this.

`library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
attach(data)
dataframe %>%
ggplot(aes(x = log(x), y = y) + geom_point() +
           geom_smooth(method = "loess") +xlab("independent variable"))`

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dataframe' not found

Error in aes(x = log(x), y = y) + geom_point() : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Try changing the name of the dataset from "dataframe" to "data" to match your dataset name.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
  coord_trans(x = "log10")
```

[image]

As you can see, there's no point at which the regression line "begins to 'dip' ".

---

## Updates

If you log-transform your x value before you plot, you end up with a figure like this:

[image]

If what you're really interested in is changepoint analysis, you can fit that.

```
data.fit <- nls(100*y ~ pmin(plat, intx + slx*log(x)), 
                  data = data,
                  start = list(plat = -32, intx = -60, slx = -4), 
                  control = nls.control(warnOnly = T))
summary(data.fit)
coef(data.fit)
```

[image]

Comment: I see your point re: non-curvature of the regression line, but when i plot the data using the log(x) scale, what I'm looking for is the point where "it begins to dip". Is there a way of fitting a curve by plotting log x vs y by first using `data$Xlog<-log(data$x)` and then fitting a model to `y~Xlog`?

Comment: There is literally no point where it begins to dip. It is always curving down at the same rate, since the slope of the line is constant. If you used `y~Xlog`, you'd have a straight line, but with the points distributed as in the second plot, which I'm guessing is not what you want. Looking at the above plots, where is the point you want to call "beginning to dip"?

Comment: Suppose I plot logX vs Y (and just assume that logX is x, rather than transforming the axis values) and fit a non-linear least squares or polynomial regression model to it; the curve would change slopes; correct?? These data are from an experiment and I'm looking for an x threshold where y begins to differ noticeably. On your second ggplot above, I guess the "dip" begins around about the tick mark to the left of the 0.01 x-value; or thereabouts. I realise in that example it's not actually a "curve" since the x scale has been log-transformed.